Integrating Android HealthConnect with Flutter mobile app
I would need your suggestion on integrating Android HealthConnect with Flutter mobile app.
Scenario:

Health vitals such as Heart Rate, SPo2, BP captured from a wearable IoTs (Smartwatches) will be stored in the dedicated mobile apps such as Samsung Health.

Using HealthConnect can read these data from Samsung Health app.

Are there anyways to read data from HealthConnect to a flutter mobile app which needs to display the vitals for tracking.
Much appreciated for sharing your suggestions.


Flutter Packages:
Tried with flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_health_connect

You can use flutter health connect but that would only target android phones and you might want to access health data in iOS devices at some point. The flutter health package allows access to both HealthConnect and AppleHealth.
Couple things to keep in mind:

Both Apple and Google require reviews for apps coming to their stores and will deny access to health data or even deployment on stores without proper permissions.
Google especially asks for developers to specify which types of health data they need and remove any you wont be using or cant explain the need for.
Accessing health data through health connect also requires setting the proper scopes and consent screens for the associated Google Cloud Project. These can be found in your Apis & Services section.
Accessing health data through Google ALSO requires connecting your app's fingerprint from the Play Console to an API key in your project (Also found in APIs & Services)

Theres probably more but there was a lot but I cant remember anything else right now. Good luck!
